# Find subsets of a set in python (order does not matter)

Tags: python, subset, powerset

I need to find the subsets of a set  `L = [0, 3, 4, 6, 9, 11, 12, 13]`.
I saw online the following solution:

```
def powerset(s):
    x = len(s)
    masks = [1 << i for i in range(x)]
    for i in range(1 << x):
        yield [ss for mask, ss in zip(masks, s) if i & mask]

print(list(powerset(L)))
```

However, this code will also return my full set L and an empty set which I do not want.

I was looking for a way to do this directly in python without using any additional packages.

Comment: What do you mean by subset?

Comment: By definition, the power set (the set of subsets of a set) contains the empty set, the 1-element subsets (if there are any), the 2-element subsets (if there are any), and so on, and the set itself. Example: the power set of `{x, y, z}` is: `{{}, {x}, {y}, {z}, {x, y}, {x, z}, {y, z}, {x, y, z}}`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set.

Comment: I just ran the code and the set is returned in the same order, so not sure what you mean ... Also strictly speaking sets don't have order

Comment: Example: ``` L = [0,1,2] ``` then ```my_Subsets = [(0,), (1,), (2,), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]```

Comment: Yeah my bad about the order. I will modify the question now

Comment: I changed the question. Hopefully, now it is more clear

Comment: Change `range(1 << x)`  to `range(1, (1 << x)-1)` to ignore the empty and full set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty simple solution. I did it as a list of sets, but you could easily swap to a list of tuples if you'd rather.

```py
def subsets(r):
    res = []
    for i in range(1, 2**len(r)-1):
        key = format(i, '#010b')
        res.append({x for j, x in enumerate(r) if key[~j] == '1'})
    return res

L = [0, 3, 4, 6, 9, 11, 12, 13]
print(subsets(L))
```

Edit: I just realised I pretty much just replicated the solution you already had, and probably in a less efficient way. Oh well I will leave this up as it does answer the question.